# Mapping n-ary relationships to relational tables

Tags: database, entity-relationship

What be the correct way to map an n-ary relationship like the one I included?
Would I do something like this?

Store(**Store**, Address, Phone Number)

Market(**Product ID**, Product Name, Product Type, Price)

Sales(**Order ID**, Quantity, Customer Name)

Inventory(**Product ID**, Quantity)

It is my understanding you take the primary key from each side that has "many" and include the other attributes as foreign keys. So, would you do the manages table like this?

Manages(**Order ID**, Product ID, Store Name)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the image ... you can also put INVENTORY_ID , STORE_NAME and PRODUCT_ID inside sales table ...
so sales would become something like this :

Sales(**Order ID**, Quantity, Customer Name, **INVENTORY_ID**, **PRODUCT_ID**, **STORE_NAME**)

but since it makes the table a bit messy ... we can extract the relation and make a new table for it and would become something like this ...

Manages(**Order ID**, **STORE_NAME**, **PRODUCT_ID**, **INVENTORY_ID**)
and remember all primary_key of this table is combination of all the columns.